# I want Ubuntu 14.04 as lean as possible

Tags: software-installation

While I appreciate the 1700+ packages that come default on a fresh Trusty Tahr install, I won't use 80 percent of them.  I'm thinking that it would be nice if I could use an alternate install cd to install the base system and grub and then install individual packages that I use without installing an entire Ubuntu Desktop.

Would a Lubuntu alternate install cd work for this?  Would it be better for me to use a 12.04 alternate install cd and update it (or would updating a 12.04 minimal install drag in all those packages that I don't want)?

Comment: Unless you have severe space constraints have something installed isn't a problem even if not used. 12.04 shouldn't be used in any circumstance because its support will end soon.

Answer (score 1):

I usually setup servers like this. I use the `mini.iso`

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso

This is the smallest you can go with an installer. Anything else will require you to modify the installation.

Answer (score 0):

No I think if you want to be very selective with the packages you install the best method is to start with ubuntu server and build off that.

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

It will start you with a command prompt and depending on how you install, or build your software you can define what you install and how much space it takes up.

For example after installing ubuntu server you could install the entire kubuntu desktop with this command.

```
sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop
```

Or if you wanted to install some other DE from a specific PPA, or application source you could do that as well from this point.

Also other little tricks for KDE/Plasma to install only the desktop, but no applications.

```
sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends
```

Comment: Wouldn't the *minimal* CD be better? Server has everything the desktop has, plus server specific software and RAID controller graphics and minus a desktop environment.

Comment: That is just how I have always done it.  The server version as far as I know doesn't install anything unless you select it during install.

Comment: It still has a few dependencies to it that the `mini.iso` doesn't seem to have. I've stumbled upon dependency that are missing because they are installed by default on the regular server build and desktop.